# automatically populate fields using PDF or word files using php

Tags: php, auto-populate

currently we are working on a cv management solution. we have a requirement like this.
When a user uploads his cv in any format (PDF, DOC, DOCX, RTF or TXT format.)  and we need to populate following fields by reading uploaded document.

- Name
- Email
- Address
- Contact Number

uploading documents formats will be different.

how can we do this?...

Please share ur ideas with us.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you cannot do this until the documents have particular structure .. which is your case is almost impossible .Its better to get a form filled by user before uploading document

Comment: is this possible using java or something else?

Comment: Its not about language but the problem is ..let you read a file .. how will you get which string is name ,email etc .. It is possible only if you have predefined structure with you

Comment: can we search the file using ley words such as name, email, contact nunber and etc......

Comment: You can find keyword but not there values ... how will you decide on boundaries .. I mean how will you decide where the name ,email etc ends ..